# How to check enable or disable state of an activity for each user?

Tags: android, adb, multi-user

I would like to disable an activity on secondary user using package manager `setComponentEnabledSetting` api.

```
PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    myComponent,
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

I'm afraid that by disabling this component with this api would turn this component to off state in primary user.

How can I make sure that my component is disabled only on secondary user? Is there any adb shell command to test the same.

Any help on this would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid if there is any straight way to test this via adb. Did you had any success testing directly with scenario?

Comment: Yes @NightFury I do not remember exactly when, but I've seen sometimes `adb shell dumpsys <package_name>` helped me and it showed disabled component list for each user.

Comment: But I'm not able to see my activity in disabled state now with the help of dumpsys

Comment: You might try to test and confirm by using intent filter with this activity? Try to launch it afterwards. [Ref](http://www.xgouchet.fr/android/index.php?article27/enabling-disabling-activities-at-runtime)

Comment: I have an intent filter for this activity but it is not broadcasted from my terminal when i do `adb shell am broadcast -a <my_intent> -n <my_receiver>`

Comment: Is this an expected behaviour ? Since I could assume that my activity is already disabled?

Comment: If your command is perfectly alright, then it might be intended behavior. I suggest you can confirm it by making component enable for secondary user, just to see things are going in right direction